# C# code conversion

Tags: vb.net

Can someone tell help me what is the VB.NET 2010 equivalent of the following code extract:
What does the "this" gets converted to? I need a little help here please. Thanks guys.

```
public class CartItemList
{
  public CartItem this[int index]
  {
   get{ return cartItems[index];}
   set{ cartItems[index] = value;}
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a [*default property*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se6z814t.aspx) in VB, e.g.

```
Default Public Property Item(ByVal id As String) As Cart
    Get
        Return id & Now().ToString
    End Get
End Property
```

(It's not clear how the `string` is meant to be converted to a `Cart` even in the C# code, mind you...)

Comment: Sorry dude. My bad. I am tired and typed it wrong. But your answer is correct I guess. Thanks a lot for the super fast answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class CartItemList
    Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(id As String) As Cart
        Get 
            Return id + Now().ToString()
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```